# More data is not dispaying in recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an app which contains a `RecyclerView`. The first time that app is launched it sends a server request for more data; when the `RecyclerView` scroll comes to end there is a progress bar that is again sends a server request for more data. But the problem is that when scroll comes to end it is sending a server request but data is not populating in the `RecyclerView`.

`MainActivity`:

```
private List<Contact> contacts;
Contact contact;
private ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
private Random random;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    random = new Random();

    sendRequesttoServerForDeals();

    //find view by id and attaching adapter for the RecyclerView
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(recyclerView, contacts, getApplicationContext());

    //set load more listener for the RecyclerView adapter
    contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
                contacts.add(null);
                contactAdapter.notifyItemInserted(contacts.size() - 1);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        contacts.remove(contacts.size() - 1);
                        contactAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(contacts.size());

                        sendRequesttoServerForMoreDeals();

                    }
                }, 5000);

        }
    });
}
/**
 * Method is called to send server request for manual deals.
 */
public void sendRequesttoServerForDeals() {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    String dealListUrl = "URL/get?category=Amaze";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, dealListUrl.trim(), jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Server success response::" + response);
            String resultCode = "resultcode";
            try {
                int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString(resultCode.trim()));
                if (nResultCodeFromServer == ConstantInt.TRANSACTION_SUCCESS) {
                    JSONArray getJsonArray = response.optJSONArray(CResponseKey.DEAL_ARRAY.trim());
                    contacts.clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < getJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject getJsonObj = getJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            contact = new Contact();
                            contact.setEmail(getJsonObj.getString(CResponseKey.DEAL_NAME.trim()));
                            contact.setPhone(getJsonObj.getString(CResponseKey.DEAL_DETAIL.trim()));
                            contacts.add(contact);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    contactAdapter.setLoaded();
                    int arrayCount = getJsonArray.length();
                    Log.e("Mainactivity", "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Server error response::" + error);
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(ConstantInt.INITIAL_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
}
/**
 * Method is called to send server request for manual deals.
 */
public void sendRequesttoServerForMoreDeals() {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    String dealListUrl = "URL/get?category=Amaze";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, dealListUrl.trim(), jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Server success response::" + response);
            String resultCode = "resultcode";
            try {
                int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString(resultCode.trim()));
                if (nResultCodeFromServer == ConstantInt.TRANSACTION_SUCCESS) {
                    JSONArray getJsonArray = response.optJSONArray(CResponseKey.DEAL_ARRAY.trim());
                    contacts.clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < getJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject getJsonObj = getJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            contact = new Contact();
                            contact.setEmail(getJsonObj.getString(CResponseKey.DEAL_NAME.trim()));
                            contact.setPhone(getJsonObj.getString(CResponseKey.DEAL_DETAIL.trim()));
                            contacts.add(contact);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    int arrayCount = getJsonArray.length();
                    Log.e("Mainactivity", "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Server error response::" + error);
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(ConstantInt.INITIAL_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once data is applied to recyclerview, then dont call clear(`contacts.clear()`) on dataset if you dont want to remove the existing data.

Why are you setting adapter again in the web service response

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

Remove this, once the adapter set, you ust need to call `notifydatasetchanged()`

once your existing dataset(Contacts) is updated with new data from server, or call `contactAdapter.notifyItemInserted(contacts.size() -1)`
after adding each contact

Comment: I am calling sendRequesttoServerForMoreDeals()

Comment: no need to set adapter again, once data is set, just call notifydatasetchanged

Answer (score 0):

Do below modification in your sendRequesttoServerForMoreDeals().

- Remove contacts.clear();
- Remove recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
- Add contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adding all more deals.

Answer (score 0):

call recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);  onCreate

then just call contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); once the data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working example. Please check it once and quick fix for this issue is

Change the below lines of code

```
 contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    contactAdapter.setLoaded();
                    int arrayCount = getJsonArray.length();
                    Log.e("Mainactivity", "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

to

```
 contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    contactAdapter.setLoaded();
                    int arrayCount = getJsonArray.length();
                    Log.e("Mainactivity", "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
```

I am not sure this is exact answer, but try this once. But below code is working. :)

**MembersList_Activity:**

```
package com.veda.Activites;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.veda.pravra.Adapters.MembersList_Adapter;
import com.veda.pravra.Global.MyUtils;
import com.veda.pravra.Interface.OnLoadMoreListener;
import com.veda.pravra.Models.AllMember_Model;
import com.veda.pravra.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MembersList_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MembersList_Adapter contactAdapter;
    @BindView(R.id.my_recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<AllMember_Model> membersList;
    int status;
    String Message, subUrl;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_noData_memberActivity)
    TextView noData;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_allMembers:
                    membersList = new ArrayList<>();
                    contactAdapter = new MembersList_Adapter(recyclerView, membersList, MembersList_Activity.this);
                    subUrl = "hostelID=" + MyUtils.getValueFromSharedPreferences(MembersList_Activity.this, "hstl_ID", "");
                    if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                        getAllMembersList(subUrl);
                    } else {
                        MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
                    }

                    //set load more listener for the RecyclerView adapter
                    contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadMore() {
                            subUrl = subUrl + "&start=" + membersList.size();
                            if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                                loadMoreData(subUrl);
                            } else {
                                MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    MyUtils.pendingMembersList = false;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_pendingMembers:
                    membersList = new ArrayList<>();
                    contactAdapter = new MembersList_Adapter(recyclerView, membersList, MembersList_Activity.this);

                    subUrl = "hostelID=" + MyUtils.getValueFromSharedPreferences(MembersList_Activity.this, "hstl_ID", "")
                            + "&isPending=1";
                    if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                        getAllMembersList(subUrl);
                    } else {
                        MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
                    }
                    //set load more listener for the RecyclerView adapter
                    contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadMore() {
                            subUrl = subUrl + "&start=" + membersList.size();
                            if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                                loadMoreData(subUrl);
                            } else {
                                MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    MyUtils.pendingMembersList = true;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_vacatedMembers:
                    membersList = new ArrayList<>();
                    contactAdapter = new MembersList_Adapter(recyclerView, membersList, MembersList_Activity.this);

                    subUrl = "hostelID=" + MyUtils.getValueFromSharedPreferences(MembersList_Activity.this, "hstl_ID", "")
                            + "&isVacated=1";
                    if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                        getAllMembersList(subUrl);
                    } else {
                        MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
                    }

                    //set load more listener for the RecyclerView adapter
                    contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadMore() {
                            subUrl = subUrl + "&start=" + membersList.size();

                            if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                                loadMoreData(subUrl);
                            } else {
                                MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    MyUtils.pendingMembersList = false;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_members);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        membersList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MembersList_Activity.this));
        contactAdapter = new MembersList_Adapter(recyclerView, membersList, MembersList_Activity.this);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        //set load more listener for the RecyclerView adapter
        contactAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                subUrl = subUrl + "&start=" + membersList.size();
                loadMoreData(subUrl);
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadMoreData(String subUrl) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                MyUtils.BASE_URL + "Hostel/hostalUsers?" + subUrl, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            status = response.getInt("status");
                            Message = response.getString("message");
                            if (status == 1) {
                                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                JSONArray membersArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
                                for (int i = 0; i < membersArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = membersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    AllMember_Model amm = new AllMember_Model();
                                    amm.setUserID(obj.getString("userID"));
                                    amm.setMemebrName(obj.getString("userName"));
                                    amm.setFatherName(obj.getString("fatherName"));
                                    amm.setDob(obj.getString("dob"));
                                    amm.setOccupation(obj.getString("occupation"));
                                    amm.setContactNumber(obj.getString("contactNumber"));
                                    amm.setPermanentAddress(obj.getString("permanentAddress"));
                                    amm.setImage(obj.getString("image"));
                                    membersList.add(amm);
                                }
                                contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                contactAdapter.setLoaded();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MembersList_Activity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (MyUtils.isInternetAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
            subUrl = "hostelID=" + MyUtils.getValueFromSharedPreferences(MembersList_Activity.this, "hstl_ID", "");
            getAllMembersList(subUrl);
        } else {
            MyUtils.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.alerts), getString(R.string.noInternetMessage));
        }
    }

    private void getAllMembersList(String subUrl) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                MyUtils.BASE_URL + "Hostel/hostalUsers?" + subUrl, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            status = response.getInt("status");
                            Message = response.getString("message");
                            if (status == 1) {
                                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                JSONArray membersArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
                                for (int i = 0; i < membersArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = membersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    AllMember_Model amm = new AllMember_Model();
                                    amm.setUserID(obj.getString("userID"));
                                    amm.setMemebrName(obj.getString("userName"));
                                    amm.setFatherName(obj.getString("fatherName"));
                                    amm.setDob(obj.getString("dob"));
                                    amm.setOccupation(obj.getString("occupation"));
                                    amm.setContactNumber(obj.getString("contactNumber"));
                                    amm.setPermanentAddress(obj.getString("permanentAddress"));
                                    amm.setImage(obj.getString("image"));
                                    membersList.add(amm);
                                }
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
                            } else {
                                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                noData.setText(Message);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MembersList_Activity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
package com.veda.pravra.Adapters;

/**
 * Created by veda on 7/9/2017.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.veda.pravra.hosteladmin.Activites.AddMember;
import com.veda.pravra.hosteladmin.Global.MyUtils;
import com.veda.pravra.hosteladmin.Interface.OnLoadMoreListener;
import com.veda.pravra.hosteladmin.Models.AllMember_Model;
import com.veda.pravra.hosteladmin.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

import static android.R.id.message;


public class MembersList_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
    OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
    private boolean isLoading;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<AllMember_Model> contacts;
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

    public MembersList_Adapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, List<AllMember_Model> contacts, Activity activity) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.activity = activity;

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return contacts.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.members_list_row, parent, false);
            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
            AllMember_Model itemList = contacts.get(position);
            UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
            if (MyUtils.pendingMembersList) {
                userViewHolder.buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            userViewHolder.memberName.setText(itemList.getMembrName());
            userViewHolder.memberDOB.setText(itemList.getDob());
            userViewHolder.memberOccupation.setText(itemList.getOccupation());
            userViewHolder.memberAddress.setText(itemList.getPermanentAddress());
        } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts == null ? 0 : contacts.size();
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        isLoading = false;
    }

    //For alert dialog
    public void ShowPaidDetailsDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.movetopaid_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.paymentConfirmation);

        final CheckBox fullPaid = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cb_fullPaid);
        final CheckBox paidAmount = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cb_PaidAmount);
        final EditText etpaidAmount = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_PaidAmount);
        Button update = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        fullPaid.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    paidAmount.setChecked(false);
                    etpaidAmount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        paidAmount.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    fullPaid.setChecked(false);
                    etpaidAmount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Close dialog
                if (paidAmount.isChecked()) {
                    if (etpaidAmount.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        etpaidAmount.setError("Enter paid amount");
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(activity, "paid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }

    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @BindView(R.id.memberName)
        TextView memberName;
        @BindView(R.id.memberDOB)
        TextView memberDOB;
        @BindView(R.id.memberAddress)
        TextView memberAddress;
        @BindView(R.id.memberOccupation)
        TextView memberOccupation;
        @BindView(R.id.buttonsLayout)
        LinearLayout buttonsLayout;

        @BindView(R.id.btn_paid)
        Button buttonPaid;
        @BindView(R.id.btn_vacated)
        Button buttonVacated;

        public UserViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            buttonPaid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ShowPaidDetailsDialog();
                }
            });

            buttonVacated.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Vacated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AllMember_Model itemList11 = contacts.get(getPosition());
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, AddMember.class);
            i.putExtra("membersList", itemList11);
            activity.startActivity(i);
            //Toast.makeText(activity, "" + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove contacts.clear() from both method sendRequesttoServerForMoreDeals() & sendRequesttoServerForDeals()
- Replace recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter); in sendRequesttoServerForMoreDeals() to contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();